# Install MATE terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, software-installation, mate

I want to install in my Ubuntu 12.04 only the MATE terminal. I don't want to completely migrate to mate, but I just want the terminal because I think it's a cool one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install `mate-terminal` in Precise (12.04) you need a PPA:

`ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/precise-mate`

Follow the steps below…

---

First install `software-properties-common`, we need `add-apt-repository`

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

After that

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/precise-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-terminal
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks exactly what I am looking for. Testing it now...

Comment: @bioShark You're welcome =)

Comment: In 16.04 you likely don't need the ppa stuff and can just use, "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install mate-terminal".

Comment: For 18.04, see [here](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/mate-terminal)